# MixPanelでENGAGEMENTとPEOPLEを同時にTrackする方法

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

MixPanel JavaScript Api でEngagementをTrackするには　`mixpanel.track("View Page");`を使用して、PeopleのTrackを行うには `mixpanel.people.function("people以下の関数のどれか");`　を使用すると思います。

どうすれば、EngagemantとPeople関係のイベントを同時にTrackできるのでしょうか？

```
mixpanel.identify("11111");
//以下２つを一度に行いたい
mixpanel.people.increment("View Page", 1);
mixpanel.track("View Page");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

本家にも質問したところ、できないとのことでした。

また、この問題の回答が必要なくなったのでクローズにさせて頂きます。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27834987/how-to-track-engagement-and-people-into-mixpanel-with-one-call